# How can I make collection available to all views in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to include data from my `Settings` model in my header which is included on all pages.

How can I include this on all page loads? Typically I send through the `Settings` collection within in my controllers, but is there a way to do this globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your header is its own include, you can use a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) to automatically pass data to that particular view when it is rendered:

```
View::composer('your.header.include', function ($view) {
    $view->with('settings', Setting::all());
});
```

Throw that in a service provider `boot` method. `your.header.include` is the name of the view file you need the `settings` for.

Comment: if you actually want this available for 'all' views ahmad's answer would do that

Answer (score 3):

use View::share in AppServiceProvider

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views